# How do I format my text areas in django with bootstrap

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have lines similar to these describing my forms in my form class:

```
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    diagnosis = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 200, 'rows': 3}))
class Meta:
    model = Report
```

Then I render my form in my view like so:

```
{% block body_block %}
    <div class="hero-unit">
    <h2>Add a Report</h2>
    <br/>
        <div class="container">
            {% if form.errors %}
                <p style="color: red;">
                Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.</p>
            {% endif %}
            <form id="report_form" method="post" action="/add_report/">
            <table>
                {{ form.as_table }}
            </table>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <br/>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Add Report</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This all works almost as expected. My only issue is that the text area is a default size which appears to be only 26 columns wide. I have tried a few things like adding:

```
(attrs={'cols': 200, 'rows': 3})
```

to my form class, and whilst this changes the row height it seems to have no effect on the text area width. I have tried changing spans and things in bootstrap to no avail. My question is how do I make the text areas of my form format nicely to the far right of my bootstrap container/hero unit?

[image: my django form]

Hopefully this picture shows what I mean. I would like the textarea to stretch to the far right of the grey area for the diagnosis field.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    diagnosis = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'cols': 200,
        'rows': 3,
        'style': 'width: 100%'
    }))
class Meta:
    model = Report
```

Comment: This sort of works. The syntax needed changing to `'style': 'width:100%'` However 100% takes it well past the edge of the container, I found 67% worked for my screen, but that doesn't format well on different sized screens.

Comment: yes, you are right about syntax. You can also try to use bootstrap's css class, for example 'class':'col-xs-12' instead of 'style' property.